# Unexpected behavior of ScientificForm when applied to a list

Tags: list-manipulation, output-formatting

Consider

```
a = Table[1, 100]

la = Length[a]

b = ScientificForm[a]

lb = Length[b]
```

`la = 100` and `lb = 1`. This causes problems in my code.  How can I make `lb` have length of 100? Why does `ScientificForm` change the length of my list?

Comment: Well `ScientificForm[List[(* stuff *)]]` does indeed have a length of `1`. What if you do `ScientificForm /@ a`?

Comment: Notice though the question is about `MatrixForm`, the most discussions therein are true for all the functions in `$OutputForms`.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer, but a comment far too long to appear in comment box.

The documentation article for `ScientificForm` asserts

> ScientificForm acts as a "wrapper", which affects printing but not evaluation.

The documentation is misleading in this case. The wrapper `ScientificForm` is not transparent to numerical calculations -- it stops them dead. This means you should only apply it to your final calculations after all the numerical work is done.

#### Example

```
u = 4234.567890; v = 4200.0;
ScientificForm[u + v]
```

[image: result_1]

In the above, because the addition is performed before `ScientificForm` is applied, it succeeds; while in the following, because the addition is attempted after `ScientificForm` is applied, it fails.

```
ScientificForm[u] + v
```

[image: result_2]

#### Note

This discussion applies to all the following wrapper functions.

- AccountingForm
- BaseForm
- DecimalForm
- EngineeringForm
- FullForm
- MatrixForm
- NumberForm
- PaddedForm
- QuantityForm
- ScientificForm
- TableForm